# Imagemagick: How to a PNG with the highest possible quality?

Tags: images, imagemagick

I tried messing around with parameters, but it seems I can't get it to work.

Here's what I got: `convert resize 491.33 "image1.png" -quality 90 image2.png`.

The result is okay-ish, but I feel like it could be better.

FYI, the input image is a photo (generated with AI, to be precise) and I plan to use this method for many images -- some photorealistic, some not.

ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Is it the quality of _resizing_ (i.e. the smoothest possible up-scaling or down-scaling) that you are talking about, or about the compression quality of the image data (which is what `-quality` sets)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I will probably only be down-scaling. I just need as good quality as possible, as I will be printing the images.

Comment: There's an action (verb) missing from "_How to a PNG [..]?_". What are you trying to do? Upsize? Downsize?

Comment: PNG is by definition a **lossless** image format. Which means there is no such thing as "quality" in PNG. There may be different compression methods/ratios available, but output image will always be the same.
Of course quality of **resizing** is another thing, as mentioned in another comment, this depends on the resizing algorithm you choose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913401/imagemagick-resizing-and-quality-png

Comment: `-quality` has nothing to do with image *quality*, it has to do with the **compression** level value being passed to `zlib`.  Like was said PNG is a lossless bitmap image format, so before you apply any compression algorithm on that file to make the file size smaller the image *quality* is what it is, and the best you can do is manipulate it to increase the *image quality* you perceive it to [not] have.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/845394/how-is-png-lossless-given-that-it-has-a-compression-parameter

Comment: you would do `-quality 100` to get the best **compression** of the file for the smallest size; it will do nothing in terms of *visual image quality*